# Scroll View does not scroll and creates white space at the bottom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios-simulator, scrollview

I have my `UIViewController` set with a Scroll View and many items in line inside that Scroll View and pulling some information from Parse, but when I run the simulator and go to that page the view is not scrollable and I get this weird white space at the bottom of the view.

the contents inside the Scroll View are larger than the Scroll View and in the Attributes Inspector I have the Scroll View as "Scrolling Enabled" (you can see it in the image), any help would be greatly appreciated it!

Here is the image showing the white space and how I have the Scroll View set up and the Attributes Inspector

[image]

In `viewDidLoad`, I have:

```
self.title = promoDetail.shortName; 
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem; 
self.imageDetail.file = promoDetail.Image; 
self.percentDetail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", promoDetail.percent]; ; self.termsDetail.text = promoDetail.terms; 
self.detailsDetail.text = promoDetail.details; // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
[self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Firstly, adding some code will be better.
At the top of my head, I would suggest checking for the basic properties of the `scrollView` like `contentSize` (which must be greater than the `bounds`), the `userInteractionEnabled`, and `scrollEnabled`, but cannot say for sure unless you reveal some code.

Comment: I don't have much code, I only have this for the viewDidLoad:

Comment: self.title = promoDetail.shortName;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;

    
    self.imageDetail.file = promoDetail.Image;
    self.percentDetail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", promoDetail.percent]; ;
    self.termsDetail.text = promoDetail.terms;
    self.detailsDetail.text = promoDetail.details;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you may be missing
**1. Why Scrolling is not enabled**
And: Check for Content Size

**2. Why white space at bottom of screen**
And: Can you check in your project storyboard what is the height of view, is it 480 or 586, if it is 480 that means you have selected iPhone 3.5 inch UIView while you are running your app in iPhone 4 inch.